# Mapping over object nested in an object coming from API | JSX Mapping problem

Tags: reactjs, api, mapping, jsx

Data coming from API is like this, Data contains an Array of 100 objects like this. Look at the launch_failure_details I want to map over this nested object and assign reason to a property, but failing.
Have a look

```
{crew: null
details: "Engine failure at 33 seconds and loss of vehicle"
flight_number: 1
is_tentative: false
launch_date_local: "2006-03-25T10:30:00+12:00"
launch_date_unix: 1143239400
launch_date_utc: "2006-03-24T22:30:00.000Z"
launch_failure_details: {time: 33, altitude: null, reason: "merlin engine failure"}
launch_site: {site_id: "kwajalein_atoll", site_name: "Kwajalein Atoll", site_name_long: "Kwajalein Atoll Omelek Island"}
launch_success: false
launch_window: 0
launch_year: "2006"
links: {mission_patch: "https://images2.imgbox.com/40/e3/GypSkayF_o.png", mission_patch_small: "https://images2.imgbox.com/3c/0e/T8iJcSN3_o.png", reddit_campaign: null, reddit_launch: null, reddit_recovery: null, …}
mission_id: []
mission_name: "FalconSat"
rocket: {rocket_id: "falcon1", rocket_name: "Falcon 1", rocket_type: "Merlin A", first_stage: {…}, second_stage: {…}, …}
ships: []
static_fire_date_unix: 1142553600
static_fire_date_utc: "2006-03-17T00:00:00.000Z"
tbd: false
telemetry: {flight_club: null}
tentative_max_precision: "hour"
timeline: {webcast_liftoff: 54}
upcoming: false
}
```

this is how I am iterating.

```
export default class Appdata extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      datainState: [],
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://api.spaceXdata.com/v3/launches?limit=100")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) =>
        this.setState({
          datainState: res,
        })
      );
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.datainState);
    var mappedComponentData = this.state.datainState.map((i) => (
      <Datadiv
        key={i.flight_number}
        src={i.links.mission_patch_small}
        name={i.mission_name}
        flightNo={i.flight_number}
        id={i.mission_id}
        launchyear={i.launch_year}
        launchinfo={i.launch_success}
        landing={i.launch_failure_details.map((j) => j.reason)}
      />
    ));
    return <div className="datadiv">{mappedComponentData}</div>;
  }
}
```

and the component Datadiv is like this

```
export default function Datadiv(props) {
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <img src={props.src} alt="" />
      <p className="title">{props.name}</p>
      <span>{props.flightNo}</span>
      <p>
        <b>Mission Id:</b>
        {props.id}
      </p>
      <p>
        <b>Launch Year:</b>
        {props.launchyear}
      </p>
      <p>
        <b>Successful Launch: </b>
        {props.launchinfo == true ? "True" : "False"}
      </p>
      <p>
        <b>Landing failure:{props.landing}</b>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**TypeError: i.launch_failure_details.map is not a function**
I know this is an easy question. I am new to JSX so I am having a hard time.
the mapping inside is giving me trouble Please provide help.
Thanks

Comment: are you missing any code? Error is shown for mapping launch_failure_details, but in above code I see on one map i.e with this.state.datainState.

Comment: @Rohitha, have a look now, I removed it because it was wrong or giving errors now added so you can see.

Comment: You are not giving the related code where you are mapping `launch_failure_details` data but when we look at the JSON response we can see that it is not an array, it is an object. So, you can't map it like that but you can use the properties as well as other objects.

Comment: @devserkan, have a look at the Appdata component there in this line ==>landing={i.launch_failure_details.map((j) => j.reason)} <== i am messing up. what should be done

Comment: You don't need to `.map` it, it is an object. Pass it as a prop and use its properties wherever you want. The properties are `time`, `altitude`, and `reason`. You should study basic JS, especially objects and arrays before jumping the React train.

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to map an object, you will have to map it's keys and access the data. As map and filter works on array. But as I see you only need reason, below code can fetch that

```
Object.keys(launch_failure_details).filter(key => key === "reason").map(item => launch_failure_details[item])
```

It will first **filter** reason from keys of launch_failure_details using that we can fetch the data using **map**.

In datadiv component you can use props.landing?.[0].

Comment: Why not `launch_failure_details.reason`? This gives the value. In your way, you end up with an array.

Comment: If that is the case he won't be using map function. launch_failure_details.reason would be sufficient.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to explain, there is no need for a `map` :)